# Firestore makes a compuond query, but i need a single query

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, sql-order-by

I'm getting all the documents containing a certain value and ordering them by 'timestamp'.

```
 var snapshot = await Firestore.instance
      .collection('posts')
      .where('exam', isEqualTo: _doc)
      .orderBy(
        'timestamp',
        descending: true,
      )
      .limit(50)
      .getDocuments();
```

But Firestore makes a compound query and sorts by 'exam' (alphabetical) and by 'timestamp'. 
How should my code be to only query by 'timestamp'?

Screenshots:
[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGTEL.png)
[Indexes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYuZb.png)

Temporary fix: I reorder the documents.

```
  List<Post> newPost =
      snapshot.documents.map((doc) => Post.fromDocument(doc)).toList();
    setState(() {
      posts = List.from(posts..addAll(newPost));
      posts.sort((a, b) => b.timestamp.compareTo(a.timestamp));
    });
```

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: I believe you might need to change something on your indexes, just to be sure, could you also add a screenshot of the first 3 or 4 documents returned by the original query?